# Unable to install AMD Radeon HD 5450 on Ubuntu13.04 due to no display

Tags: drivers, software-installation, ati, graphics, amd-processor

So here is my issue,

I got Ubuntu 13.04 installed on a system with the following specs:

AMD Athlon 64 X2 5600+
Nf-M2 nView FM2
3 GB DDR2 800 RAM
WD 250 GB HDD
Coolmax CUG-700B 500W

I cannot install the graphics drivers without the card being installed, and when the card is installed, I cant see anything to install the drivers....help?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps, it worked for me on my HP laptop with ATI Raedon Graphics.

**Install the below packages**

> sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper
>   debconf libstdc++6   dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0
>   dh-modaliases linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-core libgcc1

**Additional packages for 64bit architectures (has to be installaed along with above packages):**

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs lib32gcc1 libc6-i386
```

**Remove old fglrx drivers**

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*

sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core
>   xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
>   libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

**Then Reboot**

```
sudo reboot
```

**Downloading and building ati driver package**

> Download the driver from [Official ATI Driver](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx)
>
> ```
> cd Downloads
> Now extract the ati driver in the current folder i.e. Downloads folder, then
> sudo sh ./amd-*.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/raring
> sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
> sudo aticonfig --initial -f
> sudo reboot
> ```

If compiz/unity is not starting then, switch to terminal and type the below commands:

```
cd ~/.config
rm -rf compiz-1 dconf gnome-session
```

**It worked for me, I hope it works for you as well**

**Test :**
You can test, whether the drivers installed by issuing following command on terminal

```
fglrxinfo
```

**Testing Speed**

```
fgl_glxgears
```

**Uninistall**

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo reboot
```